# Failed to read load session data on PHP version 7.2

Tags: php

Failed to read session data after updating php version 7.0 to 7.2

Error :

> Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path:
>   C:\xampp\tmp)

I have chacked my php.ini configuration, it's correct!

Comment: Check your htdocs  root folder permissions

Comment: Where is it located? htdocs files in xampp

Comment: yes htdocs folder permission

Comment: Unable to found htdocs. Please shere the path

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs

Comment: @ReenaMori - Why would the permissions of the htdocs-folder have anything to do with reading session data? The sessions are located in `C:\xampp\tmp` (according to the error message) so that's most likely the folder you need to check the permissions for.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson ,I will fetched same issue in past and solved by permission that`s why i will asking just check folder permission.

Comment: @TestMayank  you worked on core php ya any php framework ?

Comment: @ReenaMori - I never said you shouldn't check the folder permissions. I'm saying that you should check the permissions _on the correct folder_ which is `C:\xampp\tmp` and not the `htdocs`-folder.

Comment: This is Windows. Unless you have a very odd setup permissions are almost never the issue

Comment: It would be useful to see the FULL ERROR MESSAGE and the code involved that is throwing this error

Comment: Did the code work on PHP 7.0? Session handling had changed from PHP 7.1 to 7.2. This could possibly be an issue, although the error message might be different then.

Comment: This is the error message
Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: C:\xampp\tmp)